# What kind of tenses we use for 'today'

Tags: tense, adverbs, tense-agreement

I am a bit confused about using tenses with 'today'. Which tenses we can use with 'today'?

Are these sentences grammatical?

1. I have eaten all the food today.
2. She washes clothes today.
3. I am watching TV today.
4. I will study today.

Comment: All of those sentences are correct, in the first, you ate earlier today. In the second, she is washing clothes as we speak. In the third, you are watching TV right now. In the fourth, you are going to study later today. Does that help?

Comment: How about #2 it is a simple present not a present continuous . As we know simple present is used such for habit fact etc. But the explanation is 'she is washing clothes as we speak'--i think this one is present continuous..would you like to give some answers for this..

Comment: I'm not quite sure I know what you mean about habit fact; let's say it's Tuesday. I guess you're right that the simple present "She washes clothes today" probably infers that today is her laundry day, but perhaps we don't know when she's doing it. If it's a habit, perhaps she washes clothes on Tuesdays, or at intervals of other lengths, e.g. every other day, or on Tuesdays and Fridays.

Comment: Hmm... so if i conclude we can use 'today' in some tenses but depending on the sentence context

Answer (score 4):

Because **today** is a **span of time** and not a set point, i.e. noon or 3 0'clock, you can **use all tenses**, it just depends when you **anchor** what you're saying at a particular time.

Using **different tenses** will put you either at the beginning of the day or end of the day

> I **will watch** TV today
>   I **am watching** TV today
>   I **watched** TV today
>   I **have watched** some TV already today
>   I **had watched** some TV before **eating lunch** today

Comment: What about present simple then?